# How to hide CoreAudio's HAL plugin devices

Tags: audio, core-audio, hal

In the kernel extensions, there was setDeviceCanBeDefault() that I could hide and show audio devices. How I can achieve something similar in CoreAudio's HAL plugin? I want to hide and show my plugin, from sound devices, at runtime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implement the `kAudioDevicePropertyIsHidden` property and return `(UInt32)1` from it in your device.

Don't forget to call `PropertiesChanged()` on the host when you modify this non IO-related property. Also keep in mind that hidden devices cannot become the default device.